# 3 divs: one centered and the two others one in each side

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

I have this markup:

```
<body>
 <div class="prevBtn"> <a> < </a> </div>
<div id="player"> some code </div>
<div class="nextBtn"> <a> > </a> </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to get this layout:

[image]
Note: The previos and the next button are **close** to the #player

And i'm trying like this:

```
            .nextBtn{
                 float:left;
                 width:15%;
                 margin-top:180px;
            }
            .nextBtn a{
                float:right;
            }
            .player{
               float:left;
             width:70%;
                 margin-top:100px;
            }
            .prevBtn{
                float:right;
                 width:15%;
                 margin-top:180px;

            }
            .rightBtn a{
                float:left;

            }
```

the problem is that it doesn't stay like the layout if the resolution is too big or too small,

How can I achieve this for any resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surround it with a div with 770px + the left and right buttons width (change their widths from percent to a fixed width).

This will guarantee all are together.

Also use a `overflow: hidden` or a div with `clear:both` at the end, this will make sure everything is in place.

Comment: eeehm.. i'm not sure if i see it, i added a <div class="nContainer"> with a width of 850px and now the right <a> falls apart..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet make sure the surrounding div is wide enough, if it is 850px that means the left and right divs are 80px, make sure they are, and try adding some more pixels to the surrounding (maybe make it 860px).

Comment: thanks! with 880px i have the layout, but the problem is that it's not centered.  And as it has a fixed width i can't center it with %'s