# left and right divs attached to middle div

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to set auto width for left and right divs so that they are always attached to centered div. My example below uses `width: 20%;` for left and right divs which should be dynamic. How can I accomplish that?

I looked into these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724576/3-divs-one-centered-and-the-two-others-one-in-each-side), [2](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/), [3](http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/1/)) example for ideas but couldn't solve my problem. 3rd is what I want but it didn't work in all browsers.

Feel free to change whole code below as I'm open for better solutions but the center div has to be 850px.

Thanks

```
<style>
body
{
    background: #333333;
}
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cover
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #bababa;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #cccccc;
}
#center
{
    float: left;
    width: 850px; /*compulsory*/
    height: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;
}
#right
{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
</style>



<div id="cover">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center">CENTER</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I really want is to bring `border-bottom lines` to touch each other while expanding. As I said I'm open for better solutions.

Comment: how about the javascript solution given bellow? I'm not sure it is possible only using css..!

Comment: As you mentioned, divs go one under another in narrow view.

Comment: I updated my answer; now if the view narrows, the menus on the left and right simply disappear.

Comment: Left and right don't expand when the screen is big :)

Comment: Well they should if you have a browser that is up to date. What browser do you use?

Comment: Testing with all browsers and different screen.

Comment: well `querySelector` which is the newest command I use in my code works with IE8+, and all other browser,... so if you have javascript activated, it has to work! are you sure you looked at the last update http://jsfiddle.net/9uPe2/3/

Comment: I'm sure. There is a massive space between center and right divs. Left and right div may disappear but don't expand.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you're targeting, you might be able to use Flexbox (http://umaar.github.com/css-flexbox-demo/)

Comment: You mean while rescaling your browser you have some space between the middle and the right, but for a very short time? Try that : jsfiddle.net/9uPe2/4 (tried and working on chrome, FF, Safari, IE9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to stick to the `850px` for the middle, you will have to calculate the width of the entire document, thus using a little javascript : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uPe2/4/)

Here is the very basic javascript part.

```
function menuresize(){
  var windowWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
  var menusSize = (windowWidth-850)/2;
  if(menusSize<1){
    document.querySelector('#left').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#right').style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    document.querySelector('#left').style.width = menusSize+'px';
    document.querySelector('#right').style.width = menusSize+'px';
    document.querySelector('#left').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#right').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
menuresize();
window.onresize = function(e){menuresize();}
```

If the page is thinner or equal to `850px`, the left and right menus disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/enve/udZxt/2/embedded/result/)**

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background: #333333;
}
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cover
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:1420px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #bababa;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #cccccc;
    left:0
}
#center
{
    float: left;
    min-width:850px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;

}
#right
{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eeeeee;

    right:0
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, it has to be 850px.

Comment: left doesn't shrink though!

Comment: Everything get messed up now. Jump to next line etc.

Comment: I think the demo in the answer is the best

Answer (score 0):

Add width to center div in percentage like

```
 <style>
body
{
    background: #333333;
}
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cover
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #bababa;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background: #cccccc;
}
#center
{
    float: left;
    width: 850px; /*compulsory*/
    height: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;
}
#right
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
</style>



<div id="cover">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center">CENTER</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whole stuff must expand. Yours doesn't. There is s massive space right side of right div.

Answer (score 0):

see @Ence answer

now just add a new div inside "center" div and apply the class:

```
#middle{
  width: 200px;
  background: #f90;
  margin:auto;
}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vSvTZ/

Comment: If I set `border-bottom lines` then `#middle` div will have spaces next to it in big screens. I added a new comment to my original post.

Comment: and if you dont want the middle to shrink, the sides can't be 20% width. why do you need 20% width?